# Can I use dl_iterate_phdr to monitor an exec process?

Tags: c, linux, libc

I would like to get the base address of a process that I am calling with execl such as in the following code.

Does the approach make any sense?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_GNU
#include <link.h>

int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    printf("name: '%s'  base:'%lu'\n", info->dlpi_name, info->dlpi_addr);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    dl_iterate_phdr(callback, NULL);
    execl("/usr/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
}
```

My worry is that since its a callback it will get erased when execl is called. Hence a race condition as to how many callbacks will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to get the base address of a process that I am calling with excel such as in the following code.

The following code will not work -- `dl_iterate_phdr()` can only examine the process it is running in. By the time `execl()` starts running the new binary, *all traces of* the current process are gone and replaced with the new binary.

> My worry is that since its a callback it will get erased when execl is called. Hence a race condition as to how many callbacks will be called.

Your worry is misplaced: the `dl_iterate_ohdr()` is a *synchronous* function. It *completes* (and executes all the calls to `callback`) *before* you reach the `execl`.

The only way you can monitor `execl`d process is by using `ptrace` on it (as debuggers and `strace` do).

Comment: Would execl create a new memory map and a new pid? or would it reuse the existing mapping of the process?

Comment: `execl` _replaces_ current process image with a new one. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html. `pid` remains the same, but that's the _only_ thing that does -- _everything else_ is replaced.